Apps Script code not working - no prompt or popup as per script
i am completely new to appscript but am trying to solve this issue for my team.
Basically we have a script that runs a dashboard for monitoring daily tasks progress. There is supposed to be an alert requesting user to re-assign checker based on code below, but it's not working - no prompt / alert when we click on 're-assign'> 'Checker'. Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance!
enter image description here
      Swal.fire({
      title: 'Select new reviewer',
      input: 'select',
      inputOptions: inputOptionsPromise,
      inputPlaceholder: 'Select new reviewer',
      showCancelButton: true,
      inputValidator: function(value) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          if (value != '') {
            resolve();
          } else {
            reject('You need to select a reviewer')
            alert('Select reviewer required')
          }
        })
      }
    }).then((address) => {
      if (address.isConfirmed) {
      Swal.fire({
        type: 'success',
        html: 'Reviewer has been changed to: ' + address.value

function pullHoliday(holiday){
  document.getElementById("leavePlaceholder").innerHTML = holiday
}

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(pullHoliday).plotHoliday();

function deligateMS(ms){
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  var end = start;
  while(end < start + ms) {
    end = new Date().getTime();
  }
}



function promiseResolution (li, mp, key) {
  return li.length !== mp.length ? (deligateMS(10000), promiseResolution(li, mp, key)) :
      JSON.stringify(mp) != JSON.stringify(li) ?
          mp.find(obj => obj.address === key)?.name || 'nf' :
          promiseResolution(li, [...mp, li[mp.length % li.length]], key);
}




 //CALENDAR SCRIPT START
    var $startDate = moment().startOf("year");
    var $endDate = moment($startDate).add(12, "M").add(-1, "days");
    var $totalDays = moment($endDate).diff($startDate, "days");
    var $today = moment().dayOfYear();

    function buildCalendar() {
      var monthList = "", yesterday, daysRow, month, date, days, day;
      var i, j;
      
      // Define Months
      var days = ["S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S"];
      var months = [
        "January",
        "February",
        "March",
        "April",
        "May",
        "June",
        "July",
        "August",
        "September",
        "October",
        "November",
        "December"
      ];
      
    //Build calendar
      var startDate = moment($startDate); // Set reference date to start of year
      
      // Build weekday name row - hidden on mobile
      daysRow = "<div class='days'>";
        for (var i = 0 ; i < 37; i++) {
          day = startDate.date();
          daysRow += "<span>" + days[i % 7] + "</span>"
        }
      daysRow += "</div>"
      
      for (var i = 0; i <= $totalDays; i++) {
        date = startDate.date(); // Get start date
        day = startDate.day(); // Get start day of the week
        
        if (date == 1) { // If it's the first of the month
          monthList += "</ul></div>"; // End month div
          monthList += "<div class='month'><span class='months'>" + months[startDate.month()] + "</span><ul class='month-list'>"; // Add new month div
          
          for (j = 0; j < day; j++) {
            monthList += "<li></li>"; // Add blank list items for padding
          }
        }
        
        monthList += "<li class='weekday' id='day" + date + "' data-wkdy='" + days[startDate.day()] + "'><span class='text'>" + date + "</span><span></span></li>"; // Build the days
        yesterday = date;
        startDate.add(1, "d"); 
      }
      
      $(".leaveCalendar").html(daysRow + monthList);
      $("div.days span:contains(S)").addClass('weekend');
      $('li[id^="day"]').eq($today - 1).addClass('today');
      $(".leaveCalendar").find("[data-wkdy='S']").removeClass('weekday').addClass("weekend");
    }

    function pullHoliday(holiday){
      document.getElementById("leavePlaceholder").innerHTML = holiday
    }

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(pullHoliday).plotHoliday();

    function deligateMS(ms){
      var start = new Date().getTime();
      var end = start;
      while(end < start + ms) {
        end = new Date().getTime();
      }
    }

    function addData() {

      var jsonString = document.getElementById("leavePlaceholder").innerHTML
      var results = JSON.parse(jsonString);

      var i, j;
      
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var obj = results[i];
        absenceReason = obj.reason.replace(/\s+/g, "-").toLowerCase(); // Convert to CSS class
        startDate = moment(obj.startDate).diff($startDate, "day");
        endDate = moment(obj.endDate).diff($startDate, "day");
        
        for (var j = startDate; j <= endDate; j++ ) {
          $('li[id^="day"]').eq(j).addClass(absenceReason);

          // var text = absenceReason + "\n"

          if (absenceReason == 'official-holiday'){
            var text = "Public Holiday <br> \n"
          }
          else if (absenceReason == 'member-a-leave'){
            var text = "a <br> \n"
          }
          else if (absenceReason == 'member-b-leave'){
            var text = "b <br> \n"
          }
          else if (absenceReason == 'member-c-leave'){
            var text = "c <br> \n"
          }
          else if (absenceReason == 'member-d-leave'){
            var text = "d <br> \n"
          }
          else if (absenceReason == 'member-e-leave'){
            var text = "e <br> \n"
          }
          else if (absenceReason == 'leave-duplicate'){
            var text = ""
          }
          
          $('li[id^="day"]').eq(j).find('span:eq(1)').addClass("tooltip")
          $('li[id^="day"]').eq(j).find('span:eq(1)').append(text)
 
        }
      }
    }
      
    $(function(){
      buildCalendar();
      setTimeout(function() {
        addData()
      }, 5000);
    });

    ///CALENDAR SCRIPT END


function promiseLoadout () {
  waitFor(_ => selectLi != null && userMapping != null)
  .then(_ => 
    (promiseResolution(selectLi, userMapping, 'val'),
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(data) {
      var promiseOutput = {}
      JSON.parse(data).forEach(obj=>{
        promiseOutput[obj['userName']] = obj['userID'] + "@.com"
      })
      window.inputOptionsPromise = new Promise(function (resolve) {
        // get your data and pass it to resolve()
        setTimeout(function () {
          resolve(promiseOutput)
        }, 2000)
      })
    }).convertToJson("Users"))
  );
}


when you open the consol on the Browser, Can you see any errors?

thank you for your help! sorry, how do i get this the consol? do you mean the execution log? if yes, no errors there

I mean in the Browser, right click and then select Inspect, then check the Consol tab for any errors

yes, i just attached screenshot of the errors in my question, are you able to view it? thank you..

I can see it thank you, Can you tell us what deligateMs is? it is undefined

i couldnt find deligateMS inside any of the codes..

It is showing that it is inside a promise, inside userCodeAppPanel

sorry i found it here

function pullHoliday(holiday){
document.getElementById("leavePlaceholder").innerHTML = holiday
}
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(pullHoliday).plotHoliday();

function deligateMS(ms){
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  var end = start;
  while(end < start + ms) {
    end = new Date().getTime();
  }
}


thank you, Kindly add it in the question as well, also, we need to check where this function has been called

is there a way i can email or send you the codes? as there is a word limit here.

Edit the question and add the code needed please so that everyone can see them

done, i added the deligateMS portion.

hi Boshra, i just added a fourth part in my question - the Calendar script that we removed from the code as it caused the code to not run at all. After we excluded that, the code managed to run, but the SWAL did not popup to reassign checker.

is anyone able to identify if there is anything wrong with the Calender Script part please?

Can you check the Console again to see if there is any other errors please

it is just the deligateMS error and this one:

userCodeAppPanel:711 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: inputOptionsPromise is not defined
at userCodeAppPanel:711:25
(anonymous) @ userCodeAppPanel:711Understand this error
userCodeAppPanel:711 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: inputOptionsPromise is not defined
at userCodeAppPanel:711:25

now the issue is with inputOptionsPromise. I would recommend that you keep your eye on the Console and fix the issues one by one until you face a one you can't solve so we can help you.

i am unable to solve the issues sadly..

is there anything wrong with this part?
`function promiseLoadout () {
waitFor(_ => selectLi != null && userMapping != null)
.then(_ =>
(promiseResolution(selectLi, userMapping, 'val'),
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(data) {
var promiseOutput = {}
JSON.parse(data).forEach(obj=>{
promiseOutput[obj['userName']] = obj['userID'] + "@c.com"
})

window.inputOptionsPromise = new Promise(function (resolve) {
// get your data and pass it to resolve()
setTimeout(function () {
resolve(promiseOutput)
}, 2000)
})
}).convertToJson("Users"))
);
}

Please add a [mcve]: 1. Include the doGet function from the .gs file. 2. Reduce the HtmlOutput content to a minimum, but include the whole HTML structure: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body></body></html>
